# Can family that got their B1/B2 visas together travel separately at different times?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

Two individuals (father and son) get US B1/B2 visas. They were interviewed and granted on the basis of traveling together on hols.

They eventually couldn't travel together as scheduled.

Is it okay to travel separately as convenient or they have to travel together by all means? Will there be any issues at the port of entry?

Comment: I am not sure if the rule is general or by country. However, I have a B1/B2 Visa and I got for all my family. We have traveled separately.

Answer (score 1):

If the visa doesn't contain an annotation stating they're travelling together, they can travel separately.

As usual, they have to satisfy the CBP that they're bona fide visitors.

Comment: How do you know this annotation on the visa  - Is it a statement, word, code or mark? What does the CBP require?

Comment: @Abi A normal visa allows you to enter separately. An Annotation is a text written on the visa, and it will be in plain English. And the CBP mainly asks how long you're staying and what you'll be doing. Possibly what you do at home

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can travel separately once you have the visa. Unless there is an annotation on your visa stamp stating that you should travel together.

Nonetheless you just need to prove to the Immigration that you can finance  your stay in the US.